# jquery on() delegated events against document or more specific

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Looking at the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), is there a downside to attaching the `on()` event handler attachment to `$(document)` as opposed to being more specific?

```
$(document).on("click", "#dataTable tbody tr", function (event) {
  alert($(this).text());
}
```

vs

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

The only possible downside of binding to `$(document)` I can see is if the JS is being used across the site, there is a greater possibility of binding to the wrong element. However, I find that the readability of the `$(document)` version is slightly better. But is there a more substantial reason to prefer one vs the other?

Both examples at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UpDrb/1/).

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883902/global-vs-local-event-handler-binding-for-jquery-widget

Comment: Why do you user `.append()` instead of `.html()` when you just push HTML content and no nodes? -_-' And append is slower ! (even more with jQuery!)

Comment: Thanks! Any way to mark this question as a duplicate? I'm still new to this.

Comment: I've submitted a close-vote for the duplication.

Comment: Ok, I flagged it as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

second one is better , faster performance wise.. your are delegating the event to the closest static parent which is always better than the document itself..as it doesnot have to traverse through all the elements and document as a whole

Comment: Yes definitely for performance the second way is better. For tablet/phone, the more you bind to document the more lag you will get when you try to scroll

Answer (score 0):

Performance.

Though you would use the first one in the event that the element you are attaching the event handler to was inserted into the DOM after page load.